# SP13: Seach Results and Folders

Tags: 2013, document-library, search, search-results

**Objective:**

To create a new Results Source to pull only a certain list of documents in a search.

**Solution:**

Create a new result source and add the path URL for the specific document library.  Then add the new result source to the search box query.

**Problem:**

The problem is the documents are in folders and when I create the new result source it's creating two problems. The first problem is the Result Source is not recognizing the URL.  It recognizes up to the site name and nothing afterwards.  So I cannot point to the specific library.  The second problem is that the document library is full of folders.  Is this problem?  I created a view without the folders present - it is still not working.  Not sure if you can point to views using Result Source

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You are creating the result source with a query, correct? It should be something like this "{searchboxquery} path:"https://siteURL.com/DocumentLibraryName/*"

Comment: @RansherSingh for some reason after the site URL is has "_layouts/15/start.aspx#".  Is this right? Does it mater it has folders in the document library?

Comment: That just indicates that MDS (Minimal Download Startegy) is activated for your site. You can read about it and figure if you want it. Having folders in the document library should not matter.

Answer (score 3):

Stop using PATH and use Content Types. It makes requirements like this a breeze.

1. Create a new content type based on Document.
2. Assign the content type to the library.
3. Optionally remove the Document content type
4. Assign the documents in the library to your content type
5. Crawl the content
6. Find the content with a result source `ContentType=MyContentType`

Comment: Thank you!  Do I need to have Searching enabled?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by "Searching" enabled? The ContentType managed property is already queryable. That is all that's required for this to work.